# How to push a Docker Application Package to private registry via TLS using a self-signed certificate

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-registry, self-signed, docker-app

[docker-app](https://github.com/docker/app) is an experimental tool and I would like to use it with my self-hosted docker registry, not the centralized Docker Hub. Seemingly it's [supported](https://github.com/docker/app/issues/320#issuecomment-412439097) and based on the error message it tries to connect to my registry server but it fails with this:

`Error: Get https://domain.tld:port/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

How could I push docker app packages to my registry via HTTPS keeping the same certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the way:

```
cp /path/of/cert/ca.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/sub.domain.tld.crt
```

(substitute the correct path and (sub)domain name)

then:

```
update-ca-certificates
```

This solution works on Ubuntu 18.04, after this the `docker-app push` works as intended.
Please note that copying the `ca.crt` to docker's `/etc/docker/certs.d` directory in a way that suits `docker login` does *not* work for `docker-app`.